# Stripe JS API V2 - Can You Validate A CVC Number On The Front-End?

Tags: stripe-payments

My backend endpoint returns to my front-end app a list of card IDs associated with a user.  When a user selects one of these cards to charge a purchase against, I want them to input the chosen card's CVC and I want to run this CVC value against Stripe's servers (along with the card ID) to verify that the CVC is valid.

Is there a way to do this with Stripe's front-end JS library (I am using the V2 library)?

Answer (score 0):

There is not, no - and you can't store this yourself.  You could always have them re-enter their password instead as a method of authentication if you're concerned.